# How can I add a default value for a string array in a method?

Tags: c#, parameters, default

I have a method that takes a `string[]` as parameter, but I am unable to provide it with a default:

```
void Foo(string[] param = new[]) {
}
```

complains that the default should be a compile time constant. But what compile time constant is there as an empty array?

I know I can use `default`, but I was wondering what the syntax was explicitly, if at all possible.

Comment: You can use `null` to represent an empty array. What kind of default value do you actually need ?

Comment: @wohlstad an empty array. I don't like `null` and prefer Null-objects.

Comment: @BartFriederichs A default value must be constant expression, an expression of valuetype, an expression of default(valuetype). So only option is to set it to null for string[]

Comment: @Tej or use `default(string[])` which is pretty much the same as using `null`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/TRXdny

Comment: You could use a params array, which is an empty array by default in case no actual args are provided `void Foo(params string[] myArr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default value must be compile time value and there are no compile time const arrays in C# and your options are:

1. don't have a default value
2. use null/default

`default` will mean `null` so you'd have to change `string[]` to `string[]?`.

```
void Foo(string[]? x = default) // OK. 
{
}


void Foo(string[] x = default) // Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
{
}
```

---

To soften the blow you could:

```
void Foo(string[]? x = default)  
{
   string[] y = x ?? new string[] {};

   // use y below
}
```

or even:

```
void Foo() => Foo(new string[] {});

void Foo(string[] a) 
{
}
```

Comment: `string[] param = null` works fine, as does `string[] param = default`

Comment: `string[] a = null` works with nullable reference types off which in practice is <.NET 6 (C# 10). You said "*I don't like null*" so I assumed you have nullable reference types on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an optional parameter with the [params keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) which allows you to pass a variable number of arguments to the method.

You can refer to this page.
https://geeksnewslab.com/how-to-add-a-default-value-for-a-string-array-in-a-method/

Comment: In future questions consider adding some portion of the linked code so in case the link goes dead your answer is still useful. I have added a link to the `params` keyword documentation to mitigate that chance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**The default value must be one of the following in C# :**

1. A constant expression;
2. An expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
3. An expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type."

The arrays you created don't follow any of the above rules of C#, and it is `a reference type so there can be only one default value which is:` **null**

And one more thing, Array is a reference type, so it initializes by `new` keyword so anything which initializes by new cannot be constant thus constant of the reference type is `null`

So You can use `= null or = default`

```
void Foo(string[] param = null) {
  param = param==null ? new[] : param;
}
```

**OR**

```
void Foo(string[] param = default) {
}
```